# How to prevent accessing a Servlet unauthenticated with Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, apache, servlets, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro for my web application's admin authentication. All the admin content is placed under the */admin* directory and I have an *AdminServlet* that handles the requests to the admin features. The Admin Servlet's URL mapping is */Admin*. Shiro successfully intercepts the request and redirects to the login page if the user wants to access something under */admin*. However, I type in */Admin* to the URL bar of the browser I can essentially bypass Shiro and get to the admin page without authentication.
How can I protect my servlet so that it only performs a request if it is authenticated?

Here's the relevant bits of my code:

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp
[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/logout = logout
/admin/** = authc
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.servlet.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Whatever functionality the servlet has, it always ends up creating a *RequestDispatcher* forwarding to some file located under */admin*.

I tried putting /Admin/** (as the servlet URL mapping) into the shiro.ini file to be an authenticated content but as a result I kept getting redirected to the login page after submitting the credentials.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Your Admin Servlet `url-pattern` like this:

```xml
  <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
```

2. Add this to your `web.xml`:

```xml
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

3. Replace your `filter-mapping` with this:

```xml
  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Your `shiro.xml`:

```
  [main]
  shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp
  [urls]
  /login.jsp = authc
  /logout = logout
  /admin/** = authc
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Solved the problem by redirecting back to login if someone tries to access the restricted features, but this is helpful too!